# bootstrap: how align a input with a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to make a form in a modal, but I have a problem with the labels. The labels are on top of the input instead of inside, and are messing up the vertical alignment with the button on the right

[image]

im using bootstrap 3.3.7 and this is my code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="nombre_comercio_form">Id comercio:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_comercio_form" ng-model="nombre_comercio">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#buscadora').focus()"  data- toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalBuscarComercio">Buscar Comercio
         </button>
       </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nit_form">Codigo del plan:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nit_form" ng-model="nit_comercio">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre_payu_form">Descripcíon:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_payu_form" ng-mode="nombre_payu">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="correo_payu_form">Duración:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correo_payu_form" ng-model="correo_payu">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="plan_code_form">Valor:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plan_code_form" ng-model="plan_code">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you want the labels inside the input, use the `placeholder` attribute of input instead of labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this for the `.input-group-btn` gives this:

```css
.input-group-btn {display: block;}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Snippet**

```css
.modal .input-group-btn {display: block;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal show">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="nombre_comercio_form">Id comercio:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_comercio_form" ng-model="nombre_comercio">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#buscadora').focus()"  data- toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalBuscarComercio">Buscar Comercio
         </button>
       </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nit_form">Codigo del plan:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nit_form" ng-model="nit_comercio">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre_payu_form">Descripcíon:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_payu_form" ng-mode="nombre_payu">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="correo_payu_form">Duración:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="correo_payu_form" ng-model="correo_payu">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="plan_code_form">Valor:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plan_code_form" ng-model="plan_code">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternative Solution**

Alternatively, if you want the labels to be inside the inputs, use the `placeholder` attribute.